# SQL- Dashes causing duplication

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which returns over 150k rows.

Of these 150k there are a handful of problematic rows which are duplicated due to the "License Number" field having results with/without dashes

```
   License Number
    LA-637784
    LA637784
    LA-971867
    LA971867
    LA1177043
    LA-1177043
    LA808748
    LA-808748
```

Is there any small function that would filter out the value with/without the dash?

There are lots of other valid results with dashes so i can't just filter out all dashes.

Thanks

Comment: Add a few unique values too, and show us the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Replace()](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/replace.php) and then a distinct

```
select distinct replace(LicenseNumber, '-', '') as LicenseNumber
from MyTable
```

Comment: The query takes a very long time to run so ill test it now and get back. Thanks

Comment: By any chance would you know how to show only the rows that were removed? It removes about 8 results out of 150k

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
Select replace(`License Number`,'-','_')as rplace from MyTable
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

user where condition as "where LicenseNumber <> replace(LicenseNumber,"-","")"

or

```
select distinct(licensernumber) from (select replace(LicenseNumber,"-",""))
```